# Using DB2 with JRuby Rails 3.2 DataMapper ORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jdbc, jruby, jrubyonrails, ruby-datamapper

I recently became aware of DataMapper and see it's support for "legacy" database schemas is far superior to ActiveRecords'.  This has inspired me to give it a go, however I've run into a snag trying to convert my existing working ActiveRecord configuration accross.

Here's what I'm starting with

```
development:
  adapter:  jdbc
  driver:   com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
  url:      jdbc:db2://<SNIP>:50000/MYDB
  username: user
  password: password
```

Now the problem I'm having is how to actually convert this to something which DataMapper can use.  So far I worked out I need to use the do_jdbc adapter and I've gone through a stack of iterations to try and work out what the various settings should be.

Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no, still haven't found a solution :(